# Método só funciona ao minimizar/maximizar app

Tags: android, android-fragment, android-activity

Estou desenvolvendo um app para o TCC utilizando o [Google Places API](https://developers.google.com/places/android-api/?hl=pt-br). Uma parte do código retorna os locais/estabelecimentos próximos ao usuário. Porém, quando rodo o app e entro na classe responsável eu não tenho retorno algum. Mas, se eu minimizo o app e depois maximizo e então solicito novamente o retorno do método, aí os locais são retornados.

Ou seja, acredito ser um problema relacionado ao ciclo de vida da `Activity`, ou uso do `AssyncTask`, porém não tenho conhecimento suficiente sobre e minhas pesquisas não me ajudaram a resolver o problema.

O código abaixo é referente a classe em questão:

```
 public class PlacesAPIActivity extends AppCompatActivity implements GoogleApiClient.OnConnectionFailedListener{

    private static final String LOG_TAG = "PlacesAPIActivity";
    private static final int GOOGLE_API_CLIENT_ID = 0;
    private GoogleApiClient mGoogleApiClient;
    private static final int PERMISSION_REQUEST_CODE = 100;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_places_api);

        Button currentButton = (Button) findViewById(R.id.current_button);
        mGoogleApiClient = new GoogleApiClient.Builder(PlacesAPIActivity.this).addApi(Places.PLACE_DETECTION_API).enableAutoManage(this, GOOGLE_API_CLIENT_ID, this).build();

        currentButton.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                if (mGoogleApiClient.isConnected()) {
                    if (ContextCompat.checkSelfPermission(PlacesAPIActivity.this, android.Manifest.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION)
                            != PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED) {
                        ActivityCompat.requestPermissions(PlacesAPIActivity.this,
                                new String[]{android.Manifest.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION},
                                PERMISSION_REQUEST_CODE);
                    } else {
                        callPlaceDetectionApi();
                    }
                }
            }
        });

    }

    @Override
    public void onConnectionFailed(@NonNull ConnectionResult connectionResult) {
        Log.e(LOG_TAG, "Google Places API connection failed with error code: "
                + connectionResult.getErrorCode());

        Toast.makeText(this,
                "Google Places API connection failed with error code:" +
                        connectionResult.getErrorCode(),
                Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
    }

    @Override
    public void onRequestPermissionsResult(int requestCode, @NonNull String[] permissions, @NonNull int[] grantResults) {
        switch (requestCode) {
            case PERMISSION_REQUEST_CODE:
                if (grantResults.length > 0
                        && grantResults[0] == PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED) {
                    callPlaceDetectionApi();
                }
                break;
        }
    }

    private void callPlaceDetectionApi() throws SecurityException {
        PendingResult<PlaceLikelihoodBuffer> result = Places.PlaceDetectionApi
                .getCurrentPlace(mGoogleApiClient, null);
        result.setResultCallback(new ResultCallback<PlaceLikelihoodBuffer>() {
            @Override
            public void onResult(PlaceLikelihoodBuffer likelyPlaces) {
                for (PlaceLikelihood placeLikelihood : likelyPlaces) {
                    Log.i(LOG_TAG, String.format("Place '%s' with " +
                                    "likelihood: %g",
                            placeLikelihood.getPlace().getName(),
                            placeLikelihood.getLikelihood()));
                }
                likelyPlaces.release();
            }
        });
    }
 }
```

Comment: Não falta código? o onCreate só executa na 1ª vez que você abre  o app.

Comment: Então, mesmo na primeira vez que o onCreate é executado o retorno do método callPlaceDetectionApi() não é dado no Log. 

Na documentação do Places está exatamente assim: https://developers.google.com/places/android-api/current-place?hl=pt-br

Qual a melhor forma para garantir que o método callPlaceDetectionApi() será executado? Até porque o meu objetivo é que no App a tela principal carregue uma lista com os locais/estabelecimentos mais próximos, ou seja, essa list tem que estar pronta no momento que a View for pra tela.

Comment: Você pode exibir a view só quando retornar o callplacedetectionApi

Comment: E como eu faço isso? rs